# java.io.FileNotFoundException: null\gallery2.jpg (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: java, jsp

> java.io.IOException: An exception occurred processing JSP page
>   /upimg.jsp at line 43
>
> ```
> String s23=f1.getString();
>
>  String fpath=request.getRealPath("files")+"\\"+filename;
>  43:               f1.write(new File(fpath));
> ```

Comment: What is your question? The error message is quite clear: request.getRealPath("files") returns `null` and a folder named `null` does not exist.

Comment: I already created one folder with name files and file in build file.but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You have encountered a `FileNotFoundException`, which means the file you search doesn't exist in the path you have declared. Check whether you have given the correct path. And if you are sure about the path, then make sure the file you search is available in that path.